# position: absolute in position: relative

Tags: css

I am trying to make a 3 column layout with the 2 fixed width divs (floated left and right) and with a fluid center div that changes it's width according to display width. All of those are contained in a wrapper div.
The way that I went about doing this is by creating to divs with fixed width that are floated left and right a 3rd div that is positioned relative the wrapper div with margin right in order to leave place for the right div to show.
However the problem is that if the fluid div has content it overflows the right div, ignoring the margin-right style. Why does this happen?
It also seems that the 1111

get's preformatted for some odd reason.

The code:

```
<div style="width: 90%; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block; float: left; text-decoration: underline; min-width: ???">remove<br /> assets</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #999; position: absolute; left: 160px; margin-right: 160px;"><p>111111111111111111111111111111111111111<br />1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p></div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; float: right">111</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you would be much better off separating your styles from the HTML. Move them into a separate CSS file, and reference the elements using classes or IDs.

Comment: this is just a dummy, I know the recommendation regarding the inline styles

Comment: it would have been easier to read with separate css too, so it would have made the question better too, even if this is just dummy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using two divs floated.

On the right one, place the middle and the right divs.

All that is done via floats:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">content for the left</div>
<div class="rightContainer">
  <div class="right">right content</div>
  <div class="middle">middle content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
.rightContainer {
    float: none;
    min-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 30px;
    background: blue;
}​
.middle {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 30px;
    background: green;
}
```

example:

UPDATE: applied to your content: http://jsfiddle.net/2KXW5/1/

Comment: thank you, but why is it not working with position absolute, position relative? theoretically this should not happen

Comment: @viktor because the very long text makes the absolute positioned div extend over the relative item, view it as something that exists in an upper layer, it won't "respect" the bounds of the relative (parent), thus my suggestion of using floats, bullet-proof :)

Comment: but the margin-right style should still work since it is contained in an element that is also positioned and sees the position: relative; child. Also the 111 text seems to be rendered as if it was preformatted. If I write the 111 on different lines is display on different lines instead of one word.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by specifying the style `word-wrap: break-word;` for your center fluid div.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't work well with word-wrapping. Anyways I hope this code brings some help:

```
<div style="width: 90%; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block; float: left; text-decoration: underline; min-width: ???">remove<br /> assets</div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; float: right">111</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #999; position: relative; left: 10px; margin-right: 160px; overflow:hidden; word-wrap: break-word; "><p>111111111111111111111111111111111111111<br />1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: paragraph elemements are block-level elements.  Google it to learn more.  So if you want it to not overlap with the other  You must float it as well.

so include this in the header (or separate file - or inline if you want):

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
   float:left;
}
</style>
```

Then rearrange your divs:

```
<div style="width: 90%; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block; float: left; text-decoration: underline; min-width: ???">remove<br /> assets</div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; float: right">111</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #999; display:block; margin-left:160px; margin-right: 160px;overflow:auto;"><p >111111111111111111111111111111111111111<br />1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I know how block element work. In this case the problem does not seem to rely here and the code suggested does not work.